# How to redirect register output for failed hosts in ansible using assert or any ways

Tags: linux, filesystems, ansible, ansible-playbook, conditional

```
- name: Check the VolumeGroup has 5gb space
  assert:
    that: ansible_lvm.vgs.VG00.free_g|int >= 5
    fail_msg: 'VG has no free space'
    success_msg: "{{ ansible_lvm.vgs.rhel.free_g }}"
  register: vg00
- name: Line in file
  shell: echo -e "{{ ansible_fqdn }},VG_FREE=0" >> /tmp/failed.txt
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: "'FATAL' in vg00"
```

I need only the failed hosts to be redirected using when condition but it is not working. Any different condition will help

Comment: I need only the failed hosts to be redirected using when condition but it is not working. Any different condition will help

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are trying to use facts that do not exist (I've checked in ansible 2.9.12).

So my way of getting this to work would be:

```
---
- name: answer stack overflow
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: Get VolumeGroup "mirror" free space in GB
      shell: vgs --units G|grep mirror|awk '{print $NF}'|tr -d 'G'
      register: vg_free
    - name: report your findings
      shell: echo {{ ansible_hostname }} has {{ vg_free.stdout }} GB free on VG mirror >> /tmp/hosts_with_vg_less_than_5GB_free_report.txt
      delegate_to: localhost
      when: {{ vg_free.stdout | int }} < 5
```

Using shell module extensively is not recommended as Idempotence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) is hard to achieve but for reporting purposes - why not :) .